# Q: Mobile Push Badge Count (MarketingCloud SDK 6.0)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios

How to manage/display iOS badge number that calculate by myself like
`[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;`?

For now, MarketingCloudSDK will override the result - display unread messages when the app goes to the background.

Answer (score 2):

The MobilePush SDK will control badging if the Inbox functionality is enabled in the configuration for the SDK.

If you do not need inbox, set "inbox":"false" in the configuration file and you'll be able to set the badge.

If you are using inbox, you can attempt to set the badge in a delayed fashion in your app's background notification hander. A short dispatch_after in your own handler for UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification (maybe 1 second) which would then call `setApplicationIconBadgeNumber` for their own value.

This is untested but should be sufficient.